# US visa cancelled with prejudice, can I apply PR visa for Canada or Australia?

Tags: canada, australia, residency

My B1/B2 visa has been cancelled recently (cancelled with prejudice), I want to apply for Australia or Canada PR. Can I apply?

I was travelling with my two kids to visit my husband. My husband landed in US in the month of March on F1 visa to undergo flight training. Unfortunately the school informed him that it is going to shut down in a couple of days. So, he did not join that school and applied for another I20 and that course was going to start in the month of June. In the meantime, he planned to call us to USA as my kids were having vacation. At the port of entry, they stopped me and questioned me and told me that the school has shut down and what is ur husband doing here. I said he waiting for the other course to start in the month of June. I tried to explain them, but they cancelled mine and my kids visa and sent us back to our home country.

Answer (score 3):

There is no technical reason why you cannot apply for PR in Australia or Canada after this unfortunate event. During the course of application for immigration to other countries, you will be asked questions like "Have you ever been removed or deported from any country?". To this question, you must now answer "yes" and provide an explanation of the circumstances. (If you answer "no", and they find out about this event, you'll have bigger problems.) With the explanation you gave here, and probably some further questions, they will process your application according to the rules of the country you are applying to.

As an aside, after the events of 9/11, the US became somewhat more nervous about foreign pilots training in US flight schools. This may help explain why they took the step of denying you entry and cancelling your visa, but it's hard to say for certain. The fact that your husband had been admitted for flight training at a school that no longer exists would certainly raise the suspicions of the immigration officers.